# Adding functionality to SKStoreReviewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, skstorereviewcontroller

Is it possible to add functionality to the SKSStoreReviewController class in Swift? Specifically like adding a completion handler to the button to know if a user actually submitted a review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not presently that I'm aware. I would guess that it would get into some thorny privacy issues if you could tell when a particular review popped into the store and specifically which user sent it.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I mostly want to incentivize the review by giving in-app goodies if a user reviews the app

Comment: That's a big no-no and will get you perma-banned potentially.  From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#business) "If we find that you have attempted to manipulate reviews, inflate your chart rankings with paid, incentivized, filtered, or fake feedback, or engage with third-party services to do so on your behalf, we will take steps to preserve the integrity of the App Store, which may include expelling you from the Developer Program."

Comment: Sheesh, that's good to know. Thank you for that.